# How do I convert a Nest request object with a buffer into JSON?

Tags: javascript, express, nestjs, buffer

How do I convert a Nest request object with a buffer into JSON?
Everything I've logged either shows an array of bytes or a string.

Here is my controller:

```
export class KycresultsController {
  @Post()
  create(@Body() data: any): string {
    const j = data.toJSON();

    var buf = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(data));
    var temp = JSON.parse(buf.toString());
    var f = temp.data;
    console.log(f);

    const decodedJsonObject = Buffer.from(f, 'base64').toString('ascii'); 
    console.log(decodedJsonObject);`
```

And I send this POST:

```
curl -X POST localhost:3001/kycresults -d "emsample=1&data=2"
```

I see in my logs:

```
[
  101, 109, 115, 97, 109, 112,
  108, 101,  61, 49,  38, 100,
   97, 116,  97, 61,  50
]
emsample=1&data=2
[
  101, 109, 115, 97, 109, 112,
  108, 101,  61, 49,  38, 100,
   97, 116,  97, 61,  50
]
emsample=1&data=2
```

I want to get `{emsample: 1, data: 2}`

Comment: you didn't show what's the return of `create` method. Also, if you want a JSON, you should return an object, not an `string` because then nestjs will serialize that object under the hood

Comment: your curl is basically wrong, try `curl -X POST localhost:3001/kycresults -d '{"emsample":"1","data":"2"}'` @developer